# protoc failed to find the import

Tags: grpc, protoc

```
$ protoc --go_out=module=github.com/redmcme/go-protos:. \
         --go-grpc_out=module=github.com/redmcme/go-protos:. \
        --proto_path ../protos \
          ../protos/*/**
teams.team: File not found.
teams/season.proto:3:1: Import "teams.team" was not found or had errors.
teams/season.proto:22:18: "team.Team" is not defined.
```

Build command ^

```
$ ltt ../protos
../protos
├── skyblock
│  └── player.proto
└── teams
   ├── season.proto
   └── team.proto
```

Directory tree ^

```
// team.proto
syntax = "proto3";

package teams.team;
option go_package = "github.com/redmcme/go-protos/teams/team";

...
```

Team proto ^
// season.proto
syntax = "proto3";

```
import "teams.team";

package teams.season;
option go_package = "github.com/redmcme/go-protos/teams/season";
```

Season proto ^

Does anyone know why protoc failed to find the import

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import "teams.team" is wrong way

the true way is
import "team.proto" or import “teams/team.proto”